# How can I apply the **same** random value to multiple instances in geometry nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes, transforms, instances

.blend file:

[image]

I have a simple geometry node tree for adding wings to a butterfly body.
I would like to randomize the X & Y scales for the wings, however I need the **same** random value (X) and the **same** random value (Y) to be applied to each wing (so that they match).

Here is how the wings look without any randomization applied:

[image]

I have tried two approaches to randomize the scale of the wings:

1. Add a random value to the Scale vector input of the Instance on Points node (everything in red in the below screenshot):

[image]

This results in **different** random values being applied to each wing:

[image]

2. I also tried scaling the instances **after** realizing them, however this had the same effect:

[image]

[image]

Scaling the instances after realizing them does not appear to be an option as they will no longer scale from their origins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Random numbers are seeded not only by the *Seed* input, but also by the *ID*. If you don't connect anything to the *ID* socket, the default ID will be used, which will differ for each instance. You can remedy this by connecting an input to the *ID* socket, just as you do with the *Seed* socket.

In the following two images, the *Viewer* column in the spreadsheet shows the generated random number. The first one is using a forced ID, while the second one uses the default ID. I did this with a simple setup of my own, before I noticed that you had actually included a blend file. I'm using the images I had already made, but I have verified that it works with your blend as well.
[image: Random number when using a forced ID]

[image: Random number when using default ID]

Comment: Great explanation, thanks very much!

Comment: @SlickRed My pleasure. I'm in the process of learning GeoNodes, and I learned something from this. :)